# React output multidimensional object in render comes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm having an issue with a React app I'm working on.
I'm trying to show data on the screen and sometimes I don't have an object key available, an example:

```
<div>
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      Description
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">{description || "-"}</TableCell>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
      Company
    </TableCell>
    <TableCell align="left">
      {perimeter.Id || "-"}
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
</div>
```

My issue is that on the first TableCell element, it works if I don't have 'description' coming from the API call, showing "-".
For 'perimeter.Id', if it's not something returned on the call, I always get a TypeError: perimeter is undefined, even with the || '-' in front.

What I tried:

{(typeof perimeter.Id !== "undefined") ? 'exists' : 'nop'}

and I still get the TypeError: perimeter is undefined.

my object looks like:

```
{
 ...
  "description": "​description of the field",
  "perimeter": {
    "Id": "asdasdas-2515151-12e1d",
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `perimeter.Id || "-"`, you're trying to get `Id` from the `perimeter` object. If the perimeter object doesn't have a value for `Id`, it will use `"-"`.

The problem is that `perimeter` itself is undefined. You need something like this:

`{(perimeter !== undefined) ? perimeter.Id : "-"}`

This uses the ternary (?:) operator. You can shorten it like this:

`{perimeter ? perimeter.Id : "-"}`

If you're expecting `perimeter` to ever not have an `Id`, you'll need to change it to this:

`{(perimeter && perimeter.Id) ? perimeter.Id : "-"}`